# Solved applied econmics question. Problem is the value of TVC, TC, AVC, ATC, & AFC are all negative. Should I ignore negative value?

Tags: microeconomics

*Disclaimer: This is not a "Do my homework" type of question. Instead, this is, "I'm confused whether what I did is right or wrong?" type of question.*

If I ignore negative signs in **TVC** value, everything other values come in positive form. But is it okay to do so? If not, then the solution I have written here should be correct.

[image: Question and my solution toward it.]

Comment: I agree with your note that TC should be >= 0. The Total cost function takes a really strange form with that negative Q^3. Instead of ignoring the sign you should defentively ask the author from that question why he is implementing such a strange Cost function.

Comment: I wish I can ask the author. This was asked on the board exam. I wonder if they correct it over a phone call during the exam period. The question is really bad or might have been a typing mistake. @Armenthus